# Trace where all commands are used

Tags: indexing

I am currently coauthoring papers so I need to work on a tex manuscript that is shared by all of us. The problem is that, since the paper is long, I may very easily look over some place where my collaborators have made a comment. Currently we are using more or less traditional way of doing this: (Let the coauthor to be 'X')

```
\newcommand{\commentA}[1]{{\color{red} #1 --A}}
```

do the job for us. Is there anyway that I can have a list somewhere at the beginning of the document, that traces all places where the newly defined command \commentA is used?

Comment: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Collaborative_Writing_of_LaTeX_Documents

Comment: Have a look at the [todo package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/todo)  (or type `texdoc todo` on a unix-like system).

Comment: @Andrew `texdoc package` works from the Windows command line as well, for TeX Live (not sure about MikTeX)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how useful this can be, but you can have the line numbers where `\commentA` (or any similarly defined command) has appeared listed in the log file.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\roytrace}[1]{%
  \immediate\write\@auxout{\string\roy@trace{#1}{\the\inputlineno}}%
}
\newcommand\roy@trace[2]{}
\AtEndDocument{%
  \renewcommand\roy@trace[2]{\typeout{\expandafter\string\csname #1\endcsname\space used at line #2}}%
}


\newcommand{\commentA}[1]{\roytrace{commentA}\textcolor{red}{#1 --A}}

\begin{document}

Something

Something \commentA{else}

Again

Again \commentA{What?}

\end{document}
```

Note that this requires the usual two pass process.

The console will show

```
(./royhan.aux
\commentA used at line 20
\commentA used at line 24
)
```

Nothing that couldn't be obtained by a search in the source.